# recv() function return 0 and not able to reconnect with server when new socket created after time out

Tags: tcp, ip

I have windows TCP client application which connect to port and server IP address.
it connect to server and working fine. this application send data in every 2 second to server and get response. some time in working application recv() does not get any response and return time out 10060 the we check continuously 3 time if any response on  recv() function but it return 10060 time out every time.
then we close socket and create new socket to start new connection but at this time recv() will retirn 0 or 10054 error but not able to connect again with server.

```
//INIT TCP

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
*ConnectSocketOut =    INVALID_SOCKET;
struct sockaddr_in clientService[MAX_PRINTERS];

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        return 1;
    }

//----------------------
// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP); //IPPROTO_TCP
if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//----------------------
// The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
// IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
clientService[Index].sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService[Index].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(PortInformation[Index].IPAddress);     
     clientService[Index].sin_port = htons(PortInformation[Index].TCPPortNum);
//----------------------
// Connect to server.
WSASetLastError(0);
iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService[Index], sizeof(clientService[Index]));
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    int ErrSt = WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    *ConnectSocketOut = ConnectSocket;
    return 1;
}
else
{
    *ConnectSocketOut = ConnectSocket;              
}

 //send data

int iResult = 0;
   if (ConnectSocketOut != INVALID_SOCKET)
   { 
     DWORD timeout = 10 * 1000;
      setsockopt(ConnectSocketOut, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*)&timeout,   sizeof(timeout));
 iResult = send(ConnectSocketOut, lpBuffer, (int)dNoOFBytestoWrite, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ((iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)||(iResult!= dNoOFBytestoWrite)) {
        int ErrorSt = WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(ConnectSocketOut);
        WSACleanup();
        ConnectSocketOut = INVALID_SOCKET;
        return FALSE;
    }

    Status = TRUE;


   //Receive data

      int iResult = 0;
    do {

    if (ConnectSocketOut != INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
              DWORD timeout = 10 * 1000;
              setsockopt(ConnectSocketOut, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));


      iResult = recv(ConnectSocketOut, (char*)&ReceiveData[BytesReceived], 100, 0);
        }
        if (iResult > 0)
        {

BytesReceived += iResult;
   Status = ReceiveData[BytesReceived - 1];         
                  switch (Status)
            {
                case ACK:
                case NAK:
                {

                    AckStatus = ACK_FOUND;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    Status = UNKNOW_ACK;

                }
            }

        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
        {
            int RetVal = WSAGetLastError();
            Status = UNKNOW_ACK;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            int RetVal = WSAGetLastError();
        }

    }while ((AckStatus == ACK_NOTFOUND) && (Counter++ < 4));
    if (Status == UNKNOW_ACK)
    {
        closesocket(ConnectSocketOut);
        WSACleanup();
        ConnectSocketOut = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: please review code for TCP Init,Send data, receive data

Comment: You didn't even write which programming language you are using. Please give more information so people can help you better.

Comment: please see the code in edited post

Comment: You are trying to send and receive messages but you don't seem to have any message protocol. That will not work reliably even if it seems to work some of the time. Where is the code to receive a *message*?

Comment: in above post code is present for receive message

Comment: 10060 in an established connection followed by 10054 on subsequent connection attempts is what you'd get if the server had exited.  Are you sure it's still running?

Comment: yes server is running because when I send ping to server from command prompt it response. first I got 10060 after that when I close existing socket and create new socket than connect to server its able to connect and also successfully send command but when recev() function call it return 10054 or 0 continuously every time when I create new socket.